# How to properly import modules to use them in dynamically loaded modules?

Tags: angular

I have a big project which bundles all components, pipes, etc to one file. Currently, I'm trying to split it in separate bundles.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// some other imports

 @NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule
```

**app.routes.js**

```
...
export const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: 'explore',
        component: ExploreComponent,
        loadChildren: './explore.module#ExploreModule
    },
    ...
];
```

**explore.module.ts**

```
// some imports
const routes: Routes = [ ... ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declaration: [
        ExploreInfoComponent,
        ExploreFormComponent
    ]
})
export class ExploreModule {}
```

In **ExploreFormComponent** i use *ngModel* and when i add *FormsModule* to imports array of **ExploreModule** then i receive

> Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. ...

Is there something that I missed? Because all modules imported in **shared** and **app** modules seems to be invisible in **explore.module.ts**.

Comment: read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: done. Correct me if I'm wrong, as far I understand from the article, in lazy loaded module for every import will be created a copy, and in the article you describe a way how to resolve this issue for modules that you write yourself. Can you suggest something for case with angular or 3rd party modules? @maxim-koretskyi

Comment: _in lazy loaded module for every import will be created a copy_ - sorry, I don't understand what you mean here

Comment: never mind, the problem was in 3rd party resources

Answer (score 0):

> You should only import `BrowserModule` once. Other modules you import
>   should be importing `CommonModules` instead.

Also as pointed by @Maxim you should export the modules in shared modules to be used by all the modules in your app by placing the components in the `exports` array of module

Comment: *BrowserModule* imported once in **app.module.ts**

Comment: have you imported common modules for the rest @АлександрБуклей